# How to encode CBOR from the decoding buffer

Tags: node.js, encoding, buffer, decoding, cbor

Buffer is not returning the same when decoding then encoding then decoding of CBOR.

```
const greenpassData = cbor.decodeAllSync(cbor_data);

// --------------------------------
//Want the CBOR data after decoding  CBOR Data

const greenpassDataEncode = cbor.encode(greenpassData);

console.log(greenpassDataEncode);
console.log(cbor_data);
```

Complete Code How to decode the GreenPass QR code.
Simple green pass decoder inspired by https://git.gir.st/greenpass.git/blob_plain/master:/greenpass.py
Complete Code How to decode the GreenPass QR code.
Simple green pass decoder inspired by https://git.gir.st/greenpass.git/blob_plain/master:/greenpass.py
Complete Code How to decode the GreenPass QR code.
Simple green pass decoder inspired by https://git.gir.st/greenpass.git/blob_plain/master:/greenpass.py
Complete Code How to decode the GreenPass QR code.
Simple green pass decoder inspired by https://git.gir.st/greenpass.git/blob_plain/master:/greenpass.py

```
/**
 * Simple green pass decoder inspired by https://git.gir.st/greenpass.git/blob_plain/master:/greenpass.py
 *
 * 2021 Lorenzo Millucci
 * 
 * Before usage install following dependecies `npm install base45 cbor jpeg-js jsqr pako`
 */

const base45 = require('base45');
const cbor = require('cbor');
const fs = require('fs');
const jpeg = require('jpeg-js');
const jsQR = require("jsqr");
const pako = require('pako');

// Set the path to the green pass QR
const FILE_PATH = __dirname + '/greenpass.jpeg';

// Read image file
const greenpassJpeg = fs.readFileSync(FILE_PATH);
const greenpassImageData = jpeg.decode(greenpassJpeg, { useTArray: true });

// Decode QR
const decodedGreenpass = jsQR(greenpassImageData.data, greenpassImageData.width, greenpassImageData.height);

// Remove `HC1:` from the string
const greenpassBody = decodedGreenpass.data.substr(4);
console.log(greenpassBody)

// Data is Base45 encoded
const decodedData = base45.decode(greenpassBody);

// And zipped
const output = pako.inflate(decodedData);
const results = cbor.decodeAllSync(output);
[headers1, headers2, cbor_data, signature] = results[0].value;

const greenpassData = cbor.decodeAllSync(cbor_data);

// --------------------------------
//Want the cbor data after decoding  cbor Data

const greenpassDataEncode = cbor.encode(greenpassData);

console.log(greenpassDataEncode);
console.log(cbor_data);
// --------------------------------

var josnString = JSON.stringify(greenpassData[0].get(-260).get(1), null, 2);
//new Encoded Array
const ecodeArrayGreenPassData = cbor.encode(greenpassData);
const greenpassData2 = cbor.decodeAllSync(ecodeArrayGreenPassData);
```

Comment: I'm wondering this too. There is some weird first item in buffer, when slicing, the buffers are same

console.log('c', cbor_data);
console.log('g', greenpassDataEncode.slice(1));

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because..

Err..

Let your console log what Pako creates, this should look something like:

```
 Uint8Array(350) [
  210, 132,  67, 
   ....
   35,  68,  98,  99,
  ... 250 more items
]
```

..while plain cbor.encode() builds from the decodeAllSync result  something like this:

```
<Buffer 11 21 31 41 51 61 ... 302 more bytes>
```

..you are missing this point:

```
const build = new Uint8Array(cbor.encode(my-decode-result))
```

Have fun!

(..but honestly: took me a little while also.. the rest of the way back, however, should be easier.)

Comment: Oh.. Just recognized: i don't use "cbor.decodeAllSync()" (which returns an array), but "cbor.decode()" (..returns object). ..like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

My friend, here is the prototype of `cbor.decodeAllSync()`:

```
static decodeAllSync(input: BufferLike, options?: DecoderOptions | string): Array<ExtendedResults> | Array<any>;
```

It returns an array. Therefore, you are passing an array to `cbor.encode()` which is encoded with the `0x81` header (hence the extra byte).

Your code will work as expected with:

```js
const greenpassDataEncode = cbor.encode(greenpassData[0]);
```

In place of:

```js
const greenpassDataEncode = cbor.encode(greenpassData);
```